# Rails combined two form fields into one

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

How do I combined the day and time into a "start_time" variable (and "end_time") before submitting? JS?

```
 <%= form_for @task do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
          <div class="time_selectors">
            <%= f.label :start_time %>
            <%= f.text_field :start_time, :class => 'datepicker' %>
            <select class="form-control time_dropdown" id="start_hour">
              <option>Select Date</option>
            </select>
            <div class="clear_both"></div>
            <%= f.label :end_time %>
            <%= f.text_field :end_time, :class => 'datepicker' %>
            <select class="form-control time_dropdown" id="end_hour">
              <option>Select Date</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="clear_both"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="clear_both"></div>
          <%= f.submit "Create Task", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

I have them combined in my Task model, and I'd prefer to leave them combined if I can.

My JS right now doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
$('#new-task').submit ()->
  valuesToSubmit = $(this).serialize
  console.log('test')
  console.log(valuesToSubmit)
  return false
$('button').click ()->
  console.log ('test2')
```

Comment: As per my knowledge either you have to do this in your javascript or you have to reset these values at server side by date functions :)

Comment: So, how do I take whatever is in the dropdowns, add it to a new param and submit it to the controller. I figure It would be easy to parse it in the controller, but I can't seem to prevent submitting.

Comment: For future questions, you should expound upon what `doesn't work` means. What are you expecting to happen? What actually happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?

```
$('form').on 'submit', (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    start_time = ''
    start_time += $(@).find('input[name=start_day]').val()
    start_time += '_'
    start_time += $(@).find('input[name=start_hour]').val()
    $('<input/>', {type: 'hidden', name: 'start_time', value: start_time}).appendTo($(@))
    @submit()
```

(*The CoffeeScript version hasn't been tested - use the working Fiddle as your guide.)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wj4Ke/1/)